# find list of polygons from radius in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, spatial

I have stored list of polygons as Geometry object in Sql Server and then based on Lat/Long I am drawing radius around that point.

Here is the statement I used to draw the radius.

```
DECLARE @radiusInMeters FLOAT = 1000; 

DECLARE @radius GEOMETRY = GEOMETRY::Point(59.9283128,10.7132419, 4326).STBuffer(@radiusInMeters);
```

Once I get the radius I am searching for polygons falls withing that Radius using following statement.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE area.STWithin(@radius) = 1;
```

But instead of the polygons fall within the radius, I am getting all the records from my table.

Comment: I'll ask the dumb question - are all of the polygons in your table completely within 1000 meters of that point? If not, can you provide the WKT of a polygon that you think should not be returned but is? Also, a common problem with geography polygons (which you should be using btw as you're specifying objects on the Earth) is that the order in which you specify the vertices matters. Do `select area.EnvelopeAngle() from MyTableName`. If it comes back with a large value (like more than 10), you've got an ordering problem and should call `ReorientObject()` on the polygons.

Comment: @BenThul I am using Geometry and there are lots of polygons in database but I am only finding which are falls under this radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks **Barry King** for such great post.

https://sqldev.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/sql-server-spatial-geometry-radius/

Updated:

Here is the statement solved my problem.

```
DECLARE @radius INT = 1000 -- e.g. in metres
DECLARE @geo geometry = geometry::Point(10.7132419,59.9283128, 4326).MakeValid()
SET @geo = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromWKB(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromWKB(@geo.STAsBinary(),4326).STBuffer(@radius).STAsBinary(),4326)
Select @geo.STAsText()
```

Comment: It would be great if you could put the solution directly in this answer rather than linking it, as the link might break with time.

Comment: @EzLo Edited my answers :)